# quick validation method

Tags: validation

i have a form with 20 fields .. i have 2 options ...one to validate on client side and another on click of submit button do a validation from server side using ajax and show result.....

which 1 to choose...which is faster server side or client side..
i am developing a application ..its not a website.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this an application, like Microsoft Office, or a "web application," like GMail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would do both.

client side should be easy with [jquery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) if the form is nothing out of the ordinary.

server side if you use any framework at work, it could be quick. if not it's just a lot of typing.

Comment: i am using php zend framework..but not using its framework forms...but writing default forms.

Answer (score 1):

Always do server-side, regardless of speed.  Client side is optional and will be faster, but can be disabled by disabling Javascript, and you do not want to implicitly trust user input.